# Как закрыть одно всплывающее окно, а затем открыть другое на js

Tags: javascript

Наведите пожалуйста на материалы или подскажите какие изучить функции.
Нужно после клика по кнопке одно всплывающее окно закрыть и открыть другое с помощью JS.

Comment: Приложите свой код (модальных окон), чтобы понять, как именно у вас это реализовано

Answer (score 1):

Вам наверно стоит уточнить вопрос

```js
alert('Нажмите ОК для открытия другого модального окна');
confirm('Ну как, открылось?')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ниже самый элементарный подход. Но его можно развивать в зависимости от ваших нужд.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button'),
    first = document.getElementById('first'),
    second = document.getElementById('second');

// Отслеживаем клик
button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  // Закрываем первый поапа
  first.classList.remove('opened');
  
  // Открываем второй
  second.classList.add('opened');
});
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  display: none;
}
.popup.opened {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup opened" id="first">
  first
  <button id="button">toggle</button>
</div>
<div class="popup" id="second">second</div>
```

Comment: Какое же это модальное окно? Модальное окно должно блокировать весь остальной интерфейс

Comment: Тут суть в том как сделать видимым один блок и скрыть другой. Сделать так, чтобы блок перекрывал всё можно при помощи CSS. Это уже ловкость рук, но суть остается неизменной: https://codepen.io/shugich/pen/bWvoWE Если же вам нужны системные модальные окна, то это совсем другая история. В своем ответе вы описали суть.

Comment: По вопросу не до конца понятно, что нужно автору, я предположил, что именно это.

Comment: Не думал что так быстро начнут отвечать.

У меня есть несколько модальных окон.
У каждого свой id

Допустим человек открыл фото на сайте (оно в содальном окне) - , а там кнопка "купить"

После нажатия "купить" модальное окно с фото закрыть , и открыть модально окно с формой заказа.

Кто то просил код модальны окон , я использую bootstrap

Comment: А что происходит, когда человек нажимает на кнопку купить? Тут бы очень помог ваш код, конечно.

Comment: Пока ничего) - я только хочу её сделать.

Comment: Тогда не понятно что должно пропадать при клике куда.

Comment: Представьте модальное окно с id_1 , в его теле кнопка "кнопка" , при нажатии на эту кнопку , закрыть модальное окно "id_1" и открыть модальное окно "id_2"

Comment: Я поправил ответ, посмотрите это то что нужно?

Comment: Я думаю , да ! Просто не могу так быстро разобраться , попробую внедрить

Comment: Не называйте пожалуйста больше произвольные блоки [модальными окнами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE). А то при текущей постановке вопроса мой ответ правильный, а этот нет